# A json Schema with an array of a $ref or an enum

Tags: jsonschema

I would like to have a Json Schema that would enforce an array of $ref and an enum of null. I have accidentally defined a tuple - not what I want. Here is my current schema (note I must use draft-04):

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "version": "4.4.0",
    "title": "myCollection",
    "description": "Resume/CV",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "EmploymentHistories": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "oneOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "../../../Common/json/base/TextType.json#"
                    },
                    {
                        "enum": [
                            null
                        ]
                }
                ]
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an instance I would like:

```
{
    "EmploymentHistories": [
        {
            "value": "String",
            "languageCode": "aa"
        },
        {
            "value": "String",
            "languageCode": "aa"
        },
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

But I am getting an error on validation like:

File D:\Dev\Proj\Recruiting\json\resumecv\samples\Untitled5.json is not valid.
A value of type 'null' is not permitted here.
Reason: it must be of one of the following types (see below)
'string'
'object'
Hint: Either 'type' is present and doesn't contain 'null' or 'enum' is present and doesn't contain a value of type 'null'.
Error location: EmploymentHistories / 3
Details
Array item '2' is not valid.
Property 'EmploymentHistories' is not valid.
A value of type 'null' is not permitted here.
Reason: it must be of one of the following types (see below)
'string'
'object'
Hint: Either 'type' is present and doesn't contain 'null' or 'enum' is present and doesn't contain a value of type 'null'.
Error location: EmploymentHistories / 4
Details
Array item '3' is not valid.
Property 'EmploymentHistories' is not valid.

Any help is appreciated.`n`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the validator implementation you are using. It seems to be saying that `"enum": [null]` is not allowed in a schema. The error is incorrect. This should be perfectly fine. However, you can probably work around this bug by changing it to `"type": "null"`, which should have the same effect.

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct - it should not throw an error. Changing it to anyOf works and gives me the correct result. Thank you.